# How to change color of Toggle fullscreen view button

Tags: google-maps

I want to change Buttons color(Toggle fullscreen view) in Google Maps. 
Please let me know how it can be done.

[image: button details]

Comment: You can't with any documented method. Create your own buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Maps and open browser options

**More Tools -> Development Tool -> Console**

Type in console line:

```
document.getElementById("your button id").style.backgroundColor = "color"
```

To find your control, right click on it and press explore.

I don't find the fullscreen view, but to change the background color of the search box you can execute:

```
document.getElementById("searchbox_form").style.backgroundColor = "red"
```

Maybe it helps.